# Export-Csv multiple forloop results

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I have multiple forloops running with different variables pulling from .txt files. I want to export this all into a single csv file while having it look just like it does in powershell. Attached is what I get for powershell output and I would like to see the first write-host as a header in excel, followed by server name in column 1 and UP or DOWN in column 2 beneath it. 
Powershell

[image]

```
Write-Host "Starting SVR2000MS" -ForegroundColor Yellow
$servers = Get-Content C:\Users\username\Desktop\subfolder\SVR2000.txt
foreach($server in $servers){
    if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $server -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) { 
    Write-Host "$server, UP" -ForegroundColor Green
}
    else{
    Write-Host "$server, DOWN" -ForegroundColor Red
    }
}

Write-Host "Starting SVR2003DC" -ForegroundColor Yellow
$servers = Get-Content C:\Users\username\Desktop\subfolder\SVR2003.txt
foreach($server in $servers){
    if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $server -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) { 
    Write-Host "$server, UP" -ForegroundColor Green
}
    else{
    Write-Host "$server, DOWN" -ForegroundColor Red
    }
}
```

Comment: Put a sample of what you expect, it will be easier than explaining it. I don't see the difference currently between what you have and what you want

Comment: I would like to have the output (as seen in the picture) exported to csv with the yellow letters as the header followed by column 1 the IP/DNS name and column 2 the status as UP or DOWN. Still very new to this, thanks! (It won't let me add a new picture with an excel of what I'd like)

Comment: Did you at least try to just redirect the output to a file named test.csv  ?

Comment: Yes, I have tried piping to Export-CSV, Write-Output, Out-File and a combination of those. It will make the file but won't dump the output into the csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple way:

You just print it and put it in a file

Instead of `Write-Host ...`, do:

```
 "$server,UP" | Out-File test.csv -append
```

You can have more elaborate options by using objects, but it may be overkill for your needs.

If you want a clean file, you need to delete it at the beginning, because of `-append`.

BTW, no space after comma in a CSV :)

**Edit:**

`Write-Host` writes specifically ... to the host, i.e. the console, so you cannot redirect it elsewhere.

Comment: That worked! Next question is what would I need to change to put the $server variable in 1 column and the UP or DOWN status in the other?

Comment: When implementing your solution, it's putting the "IP/DNS,Status" in 1 column instead of 2 separate columns.

Comment: CSV stands for Comma Separated Values. The commais the separator, so you have $server in first column, and UP/DOWN in 2nd column. If you import your file in Excel or Calc, you **may** have to tell it that Comma is the actual separator.